# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.converter.RsaKeyConverters

Tags: java, spring-security

Итак, я подключаю к проекту Spring Security. Добавил две библиотеки:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:5.2.1.RELEASE'
implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:5.2.1.RELEASE'
```

Запускаю. Показывает:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.converter.RsaKeyConverters
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    ... 13 more
```

Ну, понятно, ищет класс и не может найти. И действительно, нет не то что класса, а и пакета, в котором он должен был бы лежать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу найти, в какой библиотеке лежит этот класс. Подскажите, где искать?
И желательно без стартера.

Answer (score 1):

Библиотека org.springframework.security.spring-security-core

Вот ссылка
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/5.2.1.RELEASE

Это ссылка на сам файл,если интересно
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/converter/RsaKeyConverters.java

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогло! :)

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую исправить удалением фактического использования при сборке версии spring-security-core младше 5.2.
Я добился этого в Maven удалением указания старой версии spring-security-core из POM здесь:

```
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
<!--            <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>-->
        </dependency>
```

Обнаружил так:
В effective-pom вижу разные версии spring-security-core:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Увидел, что этот класс появился только после c 5.2 здесь: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commit/1c25fe26c9d0241f14f28705ec585aa5c9791ae1#diff-4412eaef26b0242873cc8a9dc5533fee75014866b296e2a3e791c98936607b26